# How to set a password in google play for my app?

Tags: android, google-play

I would like to know if it is possible to set a password for downloadinf my app from google play, so only people who have this password can download it?

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but I don't think there is, since it would have a bad influence on user experience. But why would you anyways? What's your intention?

Comment: the answer is no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can't. The best thing you can do is:

1. Add security to your application

If you only want selected users to use your app, then provide some sort of security to it (at application level) via a login screen so that only users of your "service" are able to use the app by prompting them to enter an email/username and password.

2. Release the application through the Beta testing process

Google Play offers a beta testing process where you can publish your application as a Beta (or alpha) version and then make the application available to users via a shared link

Answer (score 0):

No that isn't possible. You can however require a password when the user tries to open your app for the first time. You can build your own authentication server and use for this purpose.